how to deploy a vb.net database standalone app to a new pc
I have developed a simple standalone database app using Visual  Studio 2022. My app works well on my PC, but it is not able to create the database when I tried it on a new PC. I have used SSMS to generate a script and also added the script as an "embedded resource" in my solution prior to publishing. I have been stuck at it for the last five days.
Here are the the script file, connection string and the database creator files.
The CreateDatabase() function shows an error

Database ACI2 does not exist

on the command.ExecuteNonQuery() line.
And please take it easy on me as I am learning to use VB.NET for the first time.
Connection string:
Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True

ACI.ACI_db_script.sql:
USE [master]
/****** Object:  Database [ACI2]    Script Date: 7/29/2024 12:13:57 AM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [ACI2]
CONTAINMENT = NONE
ON PRIMARY 
    (NAME = N'ACI2', 
     FILENAME = N'C:\Users\ADMIN\ACI2.mdf', 
     SIZE = 8192KB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
     FILEGROWTH = 65536KB 
    )
LOG ON 
    (NAME = N'ACI2_log', 
     FILENAME = N'C:\Users\ADMIN\ACI2_log.ldf', 
     SIZE = 8192KB, MAXSIZE = 2048GB, 
     FILEGROWTH = 65536KB 
    )
WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))

BEGIN
    EXEC [ACI2].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
END

ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET AUTO_CLOSE ON 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT GLOBAL 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET  ENABLE_BROKER 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET MULTI_USER 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 

ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET FILESTREAM(NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF) 

ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 60 SECONDS 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET ACCELERATED_DATABASE_RECOVERY = OFF  
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'ACI2')) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [ACI2]')
END

USE [ACI2]

/****** Object:  Table [ACI2].[Address]    Script Date: 7/29/2024 12:13:57 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

CREATE TABLE [ACI2].[Address]
(
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SubCity] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Wereda] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [HouseNumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

/****** Object:  Table [ACI2].[Customers]    Script Date: 7/29/2024 12:13:57 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

CREATE TABLE [ACI2].[Customers]
(
    [CustomerFullName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerType] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerStatus] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [nchar](4) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers_CustomerID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,  
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] 

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [ACI2].[NewAddress]    Script Date: 7/29/2024 12:13:57 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
               WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'ACI2' 
                 AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'NewAddress')
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE [ACI2].[NewAddress]
    @CustomerID  INT          ,
    @City        NVARCHAR (20) ,
    @SubCity     NVARCHAR (20) ,
    @Wereda      NVARCHAR (20) ,
    @HouseNumber NVARCHAR (20) 
AS  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO [ACI2].[Address] (CustomerID ,City,SubCity,Wereda,HouseNumber) 
VALUES (@CustomerID,@City,@SubCity,@Wereda,@HouseNumber); 
RETURN @@ERROR  
END')
END


/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [ACI2].[NewCustomer]    Script Date: 7/29/2024 12:13:57 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'ACI2' AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'NewCustomer')
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE [ACI2].[NewCustomer]
@CustomerID NCHAR (4), 
@CustomerFullName NVARCHAR (20),
@CustomerStatus NVARCHAR (10),
@CustomerType       NVARCHAR (20)
  
AS  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO [ACI2].[Customers] (CustomerFullName,CustomerType,CustomerStatus,CustomerID) 
VALUES (@CustomerFullName,@CustomerType,@CustomerStatus,@CustomerID); 
RETURN @@ERROR  
END')
END
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [ACI2].[UserLogin]    Script Date: 7/29/2024 12:13:57 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'ACI2' AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'UserLogin')
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE [ACI2].[UserLogin]
    @pLoginName NVARCHAR(40),
    @pPassword NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [ACI2].[Users] 
        WHERE UserName=@pLoginName AND 
        PasswordHash=HASHBYTES("SHA2_512", @pPassword)
RETURN @@ERROR  
END')
END
USE [master]
ALTER DATABASE [ACI2] SET  READ_WRITE 
`

Database Creator code:
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class DatabaseCreator
    Public Shared Sub CreateDatabase()
        Dim resourceName As String = "ACI.ACI_db_script.sql"  ' Replace with your resource name
        Dim assembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim resourceStream As Stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)

        If resourceStream IsNot Nothing Then
            Using reader As New StreamReader(resourceStream)
                Dim sqlScript As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

                ' Replace placeholders with dynamic paths
                Dim dataPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
                Dim mdfPath As String = Path.Combine(dataPath, "ACI2.mdf")
                Dim logPath As String = Path.Combine(dataPath.Replace("Data", "Logs"), "ACI2_log.ldf")
                sqlScript = sqlScript.Replace("C:\Users\ADMIN\ACI2.mdf", mdfPath).Replace("C:\Users\ADMIN\ACI2_log.ldf", logPath)

                ' Connect to SQL Server
                Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"
                Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                    Try
                        connection.Open()

                        ' Check if database exists
                        Dim existsSql = "SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'ACI2'"
                        Using existsCommand As New SqlCommand(existsSql, connection)
                            Dim exists As Boolean = CBool(existsCommand.ExecuteScalar())

                            If Not exists Then
                                ' Create database
                                Using command As New SqlCommand(sqlScript, connection)
                                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                End Using
                            Else
                                Console.WriteLine("Database ACI2 already exists.")
                            End If
                        End Using
                    Catch ex As SqlException
                        Console.WriteLine("Error creating database: " & ex.Message)
                        ' Log the error for detailed analysis
                    Finally
                        connection.Close()
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Embedded resource not found.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class


Just like you can't open a Word document without Word installed, you can't use an SQL Server database without the SQL Server database engine installed. localdb is installed with SQL Server Express. Did you install SQL Server Express on the new PC? In reality, you should install SQL Server Express on the new PC and connect to that instance, as opposed to localdb (typically for development).

Yes I did. I have installed localdb.

check your connection string. it may be different from your dev environment and on the new PC.

Regardless of whether or not the Admin user account exists, that isn't an appropriate location for the database file(s). The following may be of interest: Environment.SpecialFolder
